# Save SharePoint 2013 List Data to SharePoint 2010 List Dynamically

Tags: sharepoint-online, ootb

I came ac-cross to fussy requirement , Where I have to save the SharePoint 2013 List data into SharePoint 2010 .

Can any one help me in knowing how can I do this using WebService or through Out of Box

Answer (score 0):

Are the SharePoint 2013 and SharePoint 2010 in the same domain?

If they are in the same domain, then you could

1. Export SharePoint 2013 list data to excel and import the excel to SharePoint 2010 list.
2. Create workflow 2013 for the list in SharePoint 2013, then add call http web service to create item in SharePoint 2010 list. And trigger the workflow 2013 when the item is added in list in SharePoint 2013.

For more information, refer to the articles below.

SharePoint Designer Call HTTP Web Service to create item in other Site (Collection).

https://blog.portiva.nl/2016/11/03/sharepoint-designer-call-http-web-service-to-create-item-in-other-site-collection/

Working with Web Services in SharePoint Workflows using SharePoint Designer 2013.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/working-with-web-services-in-sharepoint-workflows-using-sharepoint-designer

Using SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow, update/create item in other site collection.

https://mysharepointexperiences.wordpress.com/2017/03/18/using-sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow-updatecreate-item-in-other-site-collection/